# Align mesh and object bounding boxes with helper axes

Tags: three.js, 3d, rotation, alignment, bounding-box

The bounding box doesn't seem to be aligned with the 3d mesh. This is the reason. Can you please give me some tips on how should I rotate the bounding box so that it's properly aligned with 3d mesh?

This is the screenshot of the 3d mesh and misaligned object bounding box:

[image: 3d_mesh]

Things I've tried:

- Tried the approach of offsetting center position from object.
- Tried to remove the rotation and translation of the object before calling 'setFromObject'.
- Tried to rotate the box directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the center point of the model's AABB in order to offset it as requested. The code for this looks like so:

```js
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );
const center = box.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() );

object.position.x += ( object.position.x - center.x );
object.position.y += ( object.position.y - center.y );
object.position.z += ( object.position.z - center.z );
```

Comment: So, I tried that but doesn't seem to work. I'm thinking instead of trying to align the scene (3d mesh) with axes, how about I just align the bounding box. I tried to offset the box position using your approach but that didn't work either. Here's what I tried:

```box.min.sub(object.position - center)
box.max.sub(object.position - center)
```

Comment: I have the axis aligned bounding box coordinates for each object. Is it possible to draw your own bounding box for each object in 3d mesh?

Comment: Try it with [Box3Helper](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/helpers/Box3Helper).

Comment: Can somebody help me fix the alignment of the bounding boxes on each object in the above 3d mesh?

Comment: Can I rotate the box for each object in the above 3d mesh so that it's aligned with the object?

Comment: Why can't I do something like this:
`var boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(object, 0xffff67)`
`boxHelper.geometry.rotateY(THREE.Math.degToRad(5))`